# UDK:In kismet Voice/Announcements aren't shown

Tags: unreal-development-kit

I'm trying to make a Puzzle game in `UDK` and when I'm on a trigger I want player to see a text in front of them but the problem is that in the tutorial I watched in kismet he goes to: 
`new action>Voice/Announcements>Play Announcement`
 but in my kismet there is no "Voice/Announcements" 
How do I make it show or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your trigger.
2. In kismet, right click, new event using trigger.
3. Select the kismet node and look at its properties. Find Sequence Object.
4. In Obj Comment, type the message you want displayed when the pawn touches the trigger.
5. Check Output Obj Comment To Screen.